# Learning IDLE for Python and I am getting stuck on the message 'continue' not in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a course via Pluralsight called Building your first Python Analytics Solution. The current module is teaching about the IDE - IDLE. The demo I am following uses a prebuilt python file called price.py that is supposed to output a list of items along with the total price. Within the example the instructor is solving for a zero entry using except and continue, as show within the picture, which works when the instructor runs it.  [Course Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBKOU.png)

But when I try to mirror the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

price_data = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/price.csv')

print(price_data.head())

price_data = price_data.fillna(0)

print(price_data.head())

def get_price_info():
    for index, row in price_data.iterrows():

        
        total_price = row['Total_Price']
        quantity = row['Quantity']
        
    try:
        price_of_a_unit = (total_price/quantity)
        print(price_of_a_unit)
    except ZeroDivisionError :
        continue


get_price_info()


plt.bar(price_data.Things, height=price_data.Total_Price)
plt.title('Barplot of Things vs Total_Price')
plt.show()
```

I get the error 'continue' not properly in the loop.

The course is using Python IDLE 3.8.
The current version that I am running is IDLE 3.10.4.

I have repeatedly gone over the code in the screenshot and it seems to me that the code is exactly the same. I have also researched the error and still could not come up with a solution that will allow me to run the script. I am really new at this and would love to understand where the issue is.

Based on a point, that the code did not match the screen shot. I reloaded the original price.py file and mage the edits needed to make it match. If I am still missing something I would be grateful to know where the mistake is.

After doing some research on try catch blocks I was able to edit the code

```
    try:
        price_of_a_unit = (total_price/quantity)
        print(price_of_a_unit)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Make sure no divisions by 0 are made.")
    except NameError:
        print("Make sure both numbers are defined.")
```

and get the code to run. Thank you

Comment: As the error states, ```continue``` only applies to within loops.  Right now, your ```continue``` is in a ```try/except``` block which isn't in the for loop.  Is your ```try/except``` block supposed to be within the for loop?

Comment: If you look at the Course Example, it will show you the code I am mirroring. When the instructor runs the same code, it works.

Comment: Your code is different from the code in the screenshot.

Comment: In your own words, how does Python know which code is inside the `get_price_info`, and which code is outside? How does it know which code is inside the `for index, row in price_data.iterrows():` loop, and which code is outside? Now, **carefully** look for differences between your code and the code on the slide, keeping that concept in mind.

Comment: You should make sure you understand both the fundamentals of Python, and some basic [debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), before attempting a project (or course, apparently) like this one.

Comment: Incidentally, what you have shown as your solution has wrong indentation again.

Answer (score 1):

Your try-except block is indented incorrectly: it runs after your for loop completes and therefore the continue statement is outside of the loop (invalid).

```py
    # loop begins
    for index, row in price_data.iterrows():

        total_price = row['Total_Price']
        quantity = row['Quantity']
    # loop ends
    # try/catch begins
    try:
        price_of_a_unit = (total_price/quantity)
        print(price_of_a_unit)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        continue # outside of a loop - invalid
    # try/catch ends
```